When is $\text{Ext}^1(T,R)$ of torsion module again torsion?
Background: This question arises as I try to compute Universal coefficient theorem for non-finitely generated modules. If $R$ is a PID, and $H$ a homology with $R$ coefficients. Let $0\to T_p\to H_p\to\bar H_p\to 0$ be the torsion decomposition where $T_p,\bar H_p$ is the torsion part and torsion free part. Dualizing this exact sequence gives
$$0\to (\bar H_p)^*\to (H_p) ^*\to (T_p) ^*=0; 0\to \text{Ext}^1(\bar H_{p-1},R)\to \text{Ext}^1(H_{p-1},R)\to \text{Ext}^1(T_{p-1},R)$$
Apply this to universal coefficient theorem, if $H_{p-1}$ has projective torsion free part, then there is a natural sequence
$$0\to \text{Ext}^1(T_{p-1},R)\to H^p\to (\bar H_p)^*\to0\tag{*}$$
If $T_{p-1}$ is finitely generated, then $\text{Ext}^1(T_{p-1},R)$ isomorphic to itself, although noncanonically. In particular, $\text{Ext}^1(T_{p-1},R)$ is a torsion module, and  clealy $(\bar H_p)^*$ is torsion free. Thus if $\text{Ext}^1(T_{p-1},R)$ is torsion module, then $({*})$ gives the torsion part and torsion-free part of $H^p$.
In fact, if $F$ is the Field of fractions of $R$, then note $F$ is divisible hence injective so $0\to R\to F\to F/R\to0$ gives $$0=\text{Hom}_R(T,F)\to\text{Hom}_R(T,F/R)\to\text{Ext}^1(T,R)\to 0$$
so $\text{Hom}_R(T,F/R)=\text{Ext}^1(T,R)$, in the case of integers, this is the dual group. And Pointryagin duality says $T\mapsto \text{Ext}^1(T,R)$ gives equivalence of  abelian profinite groups and (the opposite of) abelian torsion groups. Clealy ther are many abelian profinite groups that is not torsion(p-adic integers for example), so $\text{Ext}^1(T,R)$ is not torsion even in case of $\mathbb Z$. So what restrictions we can add(weaker than finite generation) so that  $\text{Ext}^1(T,R)$ is torsion and $(*)$ gives torsion decomposition of $H^p$?
